# How to filter mysql audit log by user account

Tags: mysql, sql, audit-logging

My issue is even i disable the **root** user from audit logging but still logging for these user. Anyone please help. Here is i did step by step.

[Setp -1] Check the audit log variable.

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'audit_log%';
+-----------------------------+--------------+
| Variable_name               | Value        |
+-----------------------------+--------------+
| audit_log_buffer_size       | 1048576      |
| audit_log_connection_policy | ALL          |
| audit_log_current_session   | ON           |
| audit_log_exclude_accounts  |              |
| audit_log_file              | audit.log    |
| audit_log_flush             | OFF          |
| audit_log_format            | OLD          |
| audit_log_include_accounts  |              |
| audit_log_policy            | ALL          |
| audit_log_rotate_on_size    | 0            |
| audit_log_statement_policy  | ALL          |
| audit_log_strategy          | ASYNCHRONOUS |
+-----------------------------+--------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

[Setp-2]
The following statement is disable audit logging for **root** account.

```
-- audit_log_include_accounts to NULL
SET GLOBAL audit_log_include_accounts = NULL;
SET GLOBAL audit_log_exclude_accounts = root@%;
```

Note: I used the **root@%** instead **root@localhost** because of this database server can access from another ip address.

[Setp-3] I call the select statement `SELECT * FROM SSVR_AUDIT_LOG` from remote PC.

[Step-4] I checked the audit log in DB server.

```
 <AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2016-04-22T03:49:11 UTC" RECORD_ID="593_2016-04-22T01:28:17" NAME="Query" CONNECTION_ID="6" STATUS="0" STATUS_CODE="0" USER="root[root] @  [162.16.22.48]" OS_LOGIN="" HOST="" IP="162.16.22.48" COMMAND_CLASS="show_create_table" SQLTEXT="SHOW CREATE TABLE `SSVR_AUDIT_LOG`"/>
  <AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2016-04-22T03:49:12 UTC" RECORD_ID="594_2016-04-22T01:28:17" NAME="Query" CONNECTION_ID="7" STATUS="0" STATUS_CODE="0" USER="root[root] @  [162.16.22.48]" OS_LOGIN="" HOST="" IP="162.16.22.48" COMMAND_CLASS="select" SQLTEXT="SELECT * FROM `SSVR_AUDIT_LOG` LIMIT 0, 1000"/>
  <AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2016-04-22T03:49:12 UTC" RECORD_ID="595_2016-04-22T01:28:17" NAME="Query" CONNECTION_ID="7" STATUS="0" STATUS_CODE="0" USER="root[root] @  [162.16.22.48]" OS_LOGIN="" HOST="" IP="162.16.22.48" COMMAND_CLASS="show_fields" SQLTEXT="SHOW COLUMNS FROM `tldssvr`.`SSVR_AUDIT_LOG`"/>
  <AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2016-04-22T03:49:13 UTC" RECORD_ID="596_2016-04-22T01:28:17" NAME="Quit" CONNECTION_ID="7" STATUS="0" STATUS_CODE="0" USER="root" OS_LOGIN="" HOST="" IP="162.16.22.48" COMMAND_CLASS="connect"/>
```

Here is my reference link [enter link description here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/audit-log-plugin-logging-control.html)

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer for my question. Here is correct answer. When you facing like that issue, you can follow below the steps.

**Audit Log Filtering by Account**

1. List all ‘audit log’ configuration items

```html
> mysql -u root -p
> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE ‘audit_log%’;
+-----------------------------+--------------+
| Variable_name               | Value        |
+-----------------------------+--------------+
| audit_log_buffer_size       | 1048576      |
| audit_log_connection_policy | ALL          |
| audit_log_current_session   | OFF          |
| audit_log_exclude_accounts  |              |
| audit_log_file              | audit.log    |
| audit_log_flush             | OFF          |
| audit_log_format            | OLD          |
| audit_log_include_accounts  |              |
| audit_log_policy            | ALL          |
| audit_log_rotate_on_size    | 0            |
| audit_log_statement_policy  | ALL          |
| audit_log_strategy          | ASYNCHRONOUS |
+-----------------------------+--------------+
```

2. To add the remote application server host name and ip address in database server.

   ```html
   > cat /etc/hosts
   > 127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4  localhost4.localdomain4
     162.16.22.48 App_PC
    ::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
   ```
3. To disable audit logging only for the application database user (root) local host and remote host accounts.

```html
> mysql –u root –p
>SET GLOBAL audit_log_include_accounts = NULL;
>SET GLOBAL audit_log_exclude_accounts = 'root@localhost,root@App_PC';
```

4. List all ‘audit log’ configuration items and check the audit_log_exclude_account value.

```html
> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'audit_log%';
> +-----------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name               | Value                      |
+-----------------------------+----------------------------+
| audit_log_buffer_size       | 1048576                    |
| audit_log_connection_policy | ALL                        |
| audit_log_current_session   | OFF                        |
| audit_log_exclude_accounts  | root@localhost,root@App_PC |
| audit_log_file              | audit.log                  |
| audit_log_flush             | OFF                        |
| audit_log_format            | OLD                        |
| audit_log_include_accounts  |                            |
| audit_log_policy            | ALL                        |
| audit_log_rotate_on_size    | 0                          |
| audit_log_statement_policy  | ALL                        |
| audit_log_strategy          | ASYNCHRONOUS               |
+-----------------------------+----------------------------+
```